# SSD failed after format. no longer can be initialized

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive

I have Windows 11 Home on a HP Laptop with an internal 500GB SSD.  I added an external 1TB SSD with a USB cable (inside a ugreen case) which was in use and working well.  Later I decided to format the new 1TB SSD and may not have allowed it to fully complete the format process before unplugging.  After that, the SSD is no longer recognized. Using disk management the following screen comes up showing a drive D but no capacity.  Right clicking only allows a drive letter change. Right clicking on the drive identifies the Western Digital 1TB SSD as a "ASMT 2235 USB Device" and says its "working properly". Any ideas on how to get the 1TB SSD to work again would be greatly appreciated.

I also used the "diskpart" command and "list drives", It shows my internal 500GB SSD as Disk 0 and its capacity.  Disk 1 is shown but 0 capacity.

[image]

Comment: Try a third-party tool such as DiskGenius, https://www.diskgenius.com/ to 1. Remove all partitions. 2. Create one new partition. 3. Format the new partition, e.g., NTFS. **Commit each step, and be sure it completes before proceeding to the next step.**

Comment: How can he remove partitions from non detected media? It does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Using disk management the following screen comes up showing a drive D
> but no capacity.

If it's connected via a USB adapter it can mean two things.

1. USB adapter failure; check with other adapter or SSD with native 'port'.
2. The SSD itself is the problem; check by connecting SSD to native 'port'. Depending on model you may be able to use shorting pins to switch to 'factory mode' or 'techno mode'. If controller is alive it should ID (but possibly with different ID than expected) and report some reduced capacity, a fraction of what you'd expect. Release short and it should leave techno mode again.

[image: Switching SSD into factory mode]

But normally if you get to 2, a data recovery specialist is the way to go if you need the data back, see https://superuser.com/a/1758901/705502

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  With regard to the USB laptop port, USB cable and Ugreen SSD case holder, these all work fine with another 1TB backup non SSD drive.  I guess that leaves the 2nd suggestion to be tried.  Data recover is not an issue. Thanks

Comment: If they work fine with other SSD then I agree USB portion is not the issue. "drive identifies the Western Digital 1TB SSD as a "ASMT 2235 USB Device"" - can we see SMART CrystalDiskInfo screenshot?

Comment: `How can he remove partitions from non detected media? It does not make sense.` No offense, but asking for SMART does not exactly make sense either. Obviously SCSI ATA PASSTHROUGH commands will have nowhere to go as well. @Cygnus77 if it isn't the enclosure that is fried, it's probably the drive (what else)

Comment: Perhaps. 'Fried' is a rather non descriptive term.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and help.  It is much appreciated.  Having a friend look at the SSD now that might know more than me.  Also checked WD site on warranty. Put in my S/N and warranty is good through 7/2027!  Then again not sure what is covered or maybe prorated but in the end will find out if nothing works.

Comment: The problem is the ASMT 2235 controller, it needs a firmware update.